# React/JSX styling code, source of standard

Tags: reactjs

Is there any source of coding standar to use in React/JSX?

For instance, in a React component:

```
<Button
  disable = {true}
  disable={true}
  value='my value'
  value="my value"
```

Where can I found an official information about it?

I've seen some standards in https://css-tricks.com/react-code-style-guide/ but that is not official, same with https://airbnb.io/javascript/react/#props

Answer (score 1):

There is no official, but the most used is the one from airbnb.

See the survey on:
https://hackernoon.com/what-javascript-code-style-is-the-most-popular-5a3f5bec1f6f

Comment: You should prove, or at least provide some link, that what you are saying is true. I mean: You said "the most used is the one from airbnb", this is something that should be explained in a better way.

Comment: There you go, a survey from hackernoon

Comment: Now it is, at least, a little bit less auto-referential. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a good starting point can be found here:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#extending-or-replacing-the-default-eslint-config

Since Create React App is a tool provided by Facebook that helps you to setup a project with React.

To be more specific, this package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app

Is the one used by default by Create React App, as explained in the package page itself:

> This package includes the shareable ESLint configuration used by Create React App.

As you can see in the npm package page, the link to the GitHub repository is this:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#readme

That is owned by Facebook.